# How do I find out why there is a discrepancy between pixel measurement in Photoshop and code?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, interface-design, css, html

I created a design spec in Photoshop that called for 50 px of padding between two rows. When the developer sent me a screenshot of the requested design in code, the 50 px was way too large. What could be causing this discrepancy in measurement? Thank you!

Comment: "Way too large" is very vague. Large like a car, large like a house, large like the Titanic? Was it 100px?

Comment: Probably the DPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What could be causing this discrepancy in measurement?"

1. design not properly executed in code
2. code not being cross-browser compliant (subset of #1)
3. creative not set to screen resolution used by developer - this discrepancy should've been brought up prior to start of the project.

At the end it's up to developer to properly execute creative direction and show proof of page maintaining pixel fidelity to creative.

Comment: I am designing on a machine with a retina display. At first, I thought it was due to this situation, but even if they set the distance to 25 pixels it is still too large. The distance is not as large as the titanic, but large enough where it looks quite odd. The resulting distance will probably be more like 16 - 18 px based on their code.

Comment: I think you are correct about the resolution of the creative. I will have to check with the developer about the crowd-browser compliance.